# Java WebStart disallow multiple instances

Tags: java, applet, jnlp, java-web-start

My WebStart applet can't work in two browsers or two browser tabs/windows. Therefore I don't want to allow running multiple instances of my applet.

Does anyone know a way to prevent a second instance of an applet from running or check if an instance of my applet is already running during initialization of a new one?

Comment: Why is the applet embedded?  It can be free floating when launched using JWS, and then the `SingleInstanceService` should work fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`SingleInstanceService`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/javaws/jnlp/javax/jnlp/SingleInstanceService.html).  See an example [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/examples.html#SingleInstanceService):

But you have to remember to unregister the instance later.  So maybe a better way (it is a hack :) ) would be to try to listen to a TCP port in the beginning and if it fails you do not start. In this way if you forgot to stop listening to the TCP port before exiting you will still be "unregistered" because the TCP port will be closed automatically by the OS.

Comment: *"See an example here:"*  See a *self contained* example [here](http://pscode.org/jws/api.html#sis).  I've never tested it with an embedded applet though.